# asciidoc section titles not working

Tags: asciidoc, spring-restdocs

I have the following asciidoc where I would like to have multiple section titles.

```
= REST API
== Token
Tokens are used for making authenticated requests to the API.
=== Getting a token
This is how you get a token
```

But it ends up looking something like this, the second section title (Token) isnt working.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to insert line breaks between each section

```
= REST API

== Token

Tokens are used for making authenticated requests to the API.

=== Getting a token
This is how you get a token
```